# Mock CakePHP's HttpSocket class

Tags: php, cakephp, mocking, tdd, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to unit test my code, and I have a datasource that uses the HttpSocket class `/lib/Cake/Network/Http/HttpSocket.php`.

The problem is that I don't want it to perform requests while testing, but I can't find a way to mock that class.

Of course I could inject it via parameter in the constructor, but I probably would have to change Cake's core, so this isn't an option.

PS: I'm not testing a model that uses this datasource, I'm testing the datasource itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your datasource class have a method that gets you the HttpSocket:

```
public function getHttpSocket() {
    return new HttpSocket();
}
```

You can then mock that method of your data source and return a completely mocked HttpSocket object and set your expectations and return values as needed.

Comment: Thanks I've ended up doing something like this (did it before you answer). But instead of making a method I've added a optional second parameter on the constructor, which is the HttpSocket object (mock). When passed the class will use it, when not will create a new instance. Works too :)